# Does Boole's inequality hold for uncountable unions?

Tags: probability, statistics

i.e. does $P(\cup _{\alpha \in S} A_{\alpha}) \le \sum_{\alpha \in S} P(A_{\alpha})$ hold for $S$ being an uncountable set?  Can someone provide a counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: Say $P(E)$ is the Lebesgue measure of $E\subset[0,1]$. For $x\in[0,1]$ let $A_x=\{x\}$.  Then $$P\left(\bigcup_{x\in[0,1]}A_x\right)=1>0=\sum_{x\in[0,1]}P(A_x).$$